# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs - Android Studio Build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I tried all solutions on Stack.

Error which i'm getting:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sensiblewallet"

    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="2.6" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <!-- Below is optional -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.sensiblewallet.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key"
            android:value="@string/applovin_sdk_key"  />
        <meta-data android:name="com.revmob.app.id" android:value="@string/revmob_media_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.revmob.FullscreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.sensiblewallet.ActivitySplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sensiblewallet.ActivityLogin"
            android:label="@string/title_screen_sign_in"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sensiblewallet.ActivityRegister"
            android:label="@string/title_screen_sign_up"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sensiblewallet.ActivityMainWallet"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>
       <!-- <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>-->
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/sdk_facebook_app_id" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.sensiblewallet" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.sensiblewallet.NotificationReciver" />

        <service android:name="com.sensiblewallet.GCMIntentService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- appgrade -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.appgrade.sdk.view.InterstitialActivity"
            android:theme="@style/InterstitialDialogTheme"/>

        <!-- supersonicads -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.supersonicads.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.supersonicads.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.supersonicads.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <!-- TrialPay's activities -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.trialpay.android.views.webcontainer.WebContainerActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|touchscreen|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.trialpay.android.views.webcontainer.WebContainerPopupActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|touchscreen|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.trialpay.android.views.videocontainer.VideoContainerActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|touchscreen|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <!-- persona -->
        <activity android:name="ly.persona.sdk.OffersActivity" />
        <!-- Tapjoy -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.tapjoy.TJAdUnitActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.ActionHandler"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.Browser"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <!-- nativex -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.nativex.monetization.activities.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nativex.videoplayer.VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />

        <!-- required Activity to show Superrewards video ads -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.playerize.superrewards.activities.SRWebViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <!-- required Activity to show AdscendMedia video ads -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.adscendmedia.sdk.ui.OffersActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>

        <!-- required Activity to show Adcolony video ads -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <!-- required Activity to show Vungle video ads -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />


        <activity
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.AdBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.AdService"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>

        <!-- Component that rewarded ADs needs -->
        <service
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.ExpService"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>
        <!-- Optional Component -->
        <receiver
            android:name="net.adxmi.android.AdReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapVideoActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapProxyActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.VASTActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.MediationTestActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle (Module:app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sensiblewallet"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("android.keystore")
            storePassword "123456"
            keyAlias "sensiblewallet"
            keyPassword "123456"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile files('libs/NativeXMonetizationSDK_v5.4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/SuperRewards-3.1b.jar')
    compile files('libs/TrialpayAndroidSdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    compile files('libs/adscendmedia1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/personasdk1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-6.1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/heyzap.jar')
    compile files('libs/revmob.jar')
    compile project(':appGradeLib')
    //compile project(':sensiblefacebooksdk')

    compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/AdxmiCustomizedSdk_v1.2.0_2015-11-13.jar')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiSdk_v5.4.0_2015-11-12.jar')
    compile project(':unity-ads')
}
```

**build.gradle (Project)**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot! Anyone see the error with this files? I searched of solutions and tried but nothing fixing my error in my project. I hope, that You will help me.
Maybe is a problem with targetSDK or minimumSDK? I haven't got idea.

Comment: the error log says 'Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs' Please can you post the logs it mentions, without those it's very difficult to know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `applovin_sdk_key` is defined in `res/values/strings.xml` along with the other values being used.

It's also suggested not to use `compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')` and use just the google play services APIs you need as described here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Your target and compile SDK versions are very new, you probably do not need  to go above `23`.  Your apps will still work on newer Android.  You do not need to have the `<uses-sdk>` tag in your Manifest when using `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in your build.gradle.